# How to speed up mariadb join tables

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

I have 2 tables from which I'm joining certain columns. They are joined on a VARCHAR column (indexed in both tables). Table A has a bit over 800.000 records and Table B has 20.000 records.
Table A has an auto_inc primary key. Table B does not have a primary key, only the index on the mentioned VARCHAR column.

The query takes about 48 seconds which is too slow. What can I do to increase the speed? Would it help to create a primary key auto_incr in table B? Even if this is not the column on which the join takes place?

Beginning user in SQL. Both tables are InnoDB and I use Mariadb.

QUERY:

```
select distinct 
    `pr`.`ProductIdentifier` AS `ProductIdentifier`,
    `pr`.`Datum` AS `Datum`,
    `pr`.`Retailer` AS `Retailer`,
    `pr`.`Prijs` AS `Prijs`,
    `pm`.`Merk` AS `Merk`,
    `pm`.`Product` AS `Product`,
    `pm`.`Formaat` AS `Formaat` 
from 
   (`prices`.`prices_table` `pr` 
    join `prices`.`product_match_table` `pm` 
        on(`pr`.`ProductIdentifier` = `pm`.`ProductIdentifier`))
```

EXPLAIN SELECT:

[Explain table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azqyw.jpg)

Comment: At a minimum, you need to show the SQL for the query that you want to speed up.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Comment: What's the query?

Comment: I have just added it in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on my knowledge of indexing in general; MariaDB may have some more specialised options I am not aware of.

However, indexes broadly speed up queries in two ways

- By only having the columns needed, meaning less data to read and process
- By being sorted in an appropriate manner to help processing

For the first, you typically need a [covering index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/#:%7E:text=A%20%22Covering%22%20index%20is%20an,considering%20at%20the%20PRIMARY%20KEY.).

For the second, this includes

- Being sorted the same way (e.g., indexed on the same fields) as tables it is being JOINed to in the query
- Being sorted so that WHERE clauses and other types of filtering can directly use the sort to go to the appropriate spot in the index/table

In practice, often the best improvement in performance is that last one - however you do not have WHERE clauses in your code there. If (as is typical) the users filter the results (e.g., only show me results where ProductName = 'Handbag') then you may need to adjust the indexes for those (more on that a bit later though).

**Covering indexes for query above**

I think with the current query (and no filtering etc) the fastest you can get is with two indexes

```
CREATE INDEX `IX_prices_ProductIdentifier` ON `prices`.`prices_table` 
    (`ProductIdentifier`,
    `Datum`,
    `Retailer`,
    `Prijs`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_productmatch_ProductIdentifier` ON `prices`.`product_match_table`
    (`ProductIdentifier`,
    `Merk`,
    `Product`,
    `Formaat`);
```

These provide covering indexes on the query shown, and are both sorted the same (by productIdentifier) to make the join easier.

**Searching/filtering (not specified in initial example)**

However, if people often search by a specific field first, then it makes sense to re-order the fields in the relevant table (so the searched field is first), or have multiple indexes with the search field at the front.

For example, people may be able to search for specific values in `pr`.`Retailer`, `pm`.`Merk`, or `pm`.`Product`. You may therefore add these additional indexes

```
CREATE INDEX `IX_prices_Retailer` ON `prices`.`prices_table` 
    (`Retailer`,
    `ProductIdentifier`,
    `Datum`,
    `Prijs`);
CREATE INDEX `IX_productmatch_Merk` ON `prices`.`product_match_table`
    (`Merk`,
    `ProductIdentifier`, 
    `Product`,
    `Formaat`); 
CREATE INDEX `IX_productmatch_Product` ON `prices`.`product_match_table`
    (`Product`,
    `ProductIdentifier`, 
    `Merk`,
    `Formaat`);
```

Notice with the above that the field orders matter. The data (index) is sorted by the first field, then the second field, then the third field etc. To use the index effectively, your filtering/WHERE clause needs to include at least the first field, if not more.

An alternate to these indexes (the ones for filtering) is to have the original two indexes as above, but then put a separate index onto each of the fields they can search on e.g., if the users can filter on the retailer, merk and product, then create

- one index on `pr`.`Retailer`
- one on `pm`.`Merk`, and
- one on `pm`.`Product`

**Caveats**

Adding indexes makes data inserts onto the relevant table (and often deletes/updates), slower than if the indexes weren't there. The reason is that it doesn't just need to update the data in the table, but it also needs to update the index(es).

Typically this is not much of a problem unless you are adding and deleting lots of data from the tables frequently. But it is worth checking your 'product maintenance' interface (e.g., adding products, updating prices etc) after adding indexes to confirm they still run well.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I tried your suggestion with the covering indexes. It saves around 10 seconds, but then still takes 38 seconds,which still seems long for me.
I'm thinking the major time is spent in matching columns rather than reading the columns behind the matching column.. There are almost 900.000 (and growing with thousands everyday) records in the prices table and 14.000 in the product_match table. Is there a way to improve this part of the query? The matching column is a VARCHAR with 125 length. I read somewhere perhaps a HASH index could help?

Comment: When users use this report, how many rows do they get back? Do they get 900,000 rows every time they run it? Or do they filter by certain columns? If so, which columns do they filter on?

Comment: The report is not used directly. The view is read by Google data studio (which already makes a filter on 'merk' in different reports).

Comment: If that's the case, I suggest adding an index on 'merk'. If that helps a lot, consider the index named `IX_productmatch_Merk` in the above answer (as a replacement for the index on merk alone).

Comment: But that does not help speed up the view correct? The problem is not filtering in Google data studio as end user. Data studio already has a filtered table and this works fine. I just think I could make the view better for future scaling (as the database will grow in a high pace).